# Node.js Crypto AES-128 encrypt stream with padding

Tags: node.js, encryption, stream, cryptography

I am successfully using NodeJS to encrypt a file in the following manner:

```
let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-128-cbc', key, iv),
    crypted = cipher.update(file_data, 'binary');
return Buffer.concat([crypted, cipher.final()]);
```

This generates a file with a hash that exactly matches our target encryption, which is server-side OpenSSL command:

```
openssl aes-128-cbc -e -in file -out file.enc -nosalt -iv <iv_str> -K <k_str>
```

The goal is to upgrade our systems to use nodejs streams. Node documentation and other posts suggest the following way to encrypt streams:

```
cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-128-cbc', key, iv);
let file_stream = fs.createReadStream(local_file, 'binary'),
    write_stream = fs.createWriteStream(`${local_file}.enc`, 'binary');
file_stream.pipe(cipher).pipe(write_stream);
```

however this ignores the `cipher.final()` appending. Without it the encryption always results in a file with the wrong hash.  I've tried:

1. creating a `Transform` that would append the remaining padding. That doesn't work because you can't call `final` on a cipher that hasn't had `update` called on it
2. setting the autopadding with `setAutoPadding`. In all cases that results in the error `Error: error:0607F08A:digital envelope routines:EVP_EncryptFinal_ex:data not multiple of block length`

How can I cipher with streams in the same way I was originally encrypting?

Comment: The stream approach is working fine for me, it is not ignoring the `cipher.final()`. Its output is the same as when running the `openssl` command. Are you sure your local file has the exact same contents as your `file_data` variable?

Comment: This code works for small sample files, but when I do large files it doesn't.

Comment: That sounds like an important detail to add to your question. What is "large"? I only tried up to a few hundred bytes.

Comment: I may be wrong here. I removed the filetype 'binary' and it started working. Apparently I wasn't understanding the filetype of the file I was working with. Thanks for your verification!